# iframes problem in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

i am using iframe to refresh captcha  whenever user makes an error in typing captcha text.

this iframe is inside a form which looks like this...

```
<iframe id="cvbnm" frameborder="0" width="176" height="75" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">     </iframe>
```

and whenever user types wrong captcha i am using

```
 $("#cvbnm").attr("src", "captcha.php");
```

where captcha.php is a different page where the captcha files are included.

this is working fine in firefox....but does not refresh in ie...
please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add a jQuery tag to this question.

What's maybe happening is that as the src is staying the same IE isn't generating a new request for the page.

Try

```
$('#cvbnm').removeAttr('src').attr('src', 'captcha.php');
```

Or

```
$('#cvbnm').attr('src', '').attr('src', 'captcha.php');
```

Update:

Ok, how about adding

```
parent.frames[FrameID].window.location.reload();
```

Or

```
document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

I must confess I'm getting this one from [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64667)